# Rounded corners on a table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

I want to add rounded corners with a border to a table row, each table row will have his separate box with rounded corners with the td in the middle, any help of the quickest and easiest way to achieve this would be good.

Comment: Give me a jsfiddle of your table and I will try to adjust it

Comment: I was only able to achieve this with separate tables, sorry:
http://jsfiddle.net/3STeh/
Border radius (rounded border) is not supported if you use border-collapse

Comment: ok thank you for your effort OmerPT, but i need it to be in the same table, so any other suggestions would be great

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle to only use one table: http://jsfiddle.net/3STeh/2/ If you need to have more than one cell in a row, then you'd have to have the first table cell with left rounded corners and the last cell with right rounded corners and the centre cells with only top and bottom borders. You could target the first and last cells with first-child and last-child.

Answer (score -2):

you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3STeh/3/